# OData Underlying Provider Failed on Open periodically

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4, odata

I have written an OData service with an EF4 model. It's currently fully functional and deployed on at least 30 different servers. The error is occuring on one of those servers but only periodically.

The server is configured and working.
At some random point it starts responding with 500 internal server errors.
The errors aren't being handled by the HandleException method that is implemented in the service.
The exception is instead dumping straight into the Windows EventLog under Application as a warning from ASP.NET 4.0.
The contents of the warning indicate that the problem is caused by the underlying provider failing on open (I'll post the full exception details at the end of the question).
When the errors are occuring I start up SQL Server Management Studio and can connect to the database without problem.
The solution to get the service working again is to simply recycle the application pool in IIS, but this is happening 2 or 3 times a week and is causing my client grief. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what might be causing this? The server is possibly the most underpowered system running the service and I've recommended a RAM increase as a starting point to potentially solve the problem but I'm flying blind here.

The full exception details:

```
    Exception information: 
    Exception type: EntityException 
    Exception message: The underlying provider failed on Open.
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
   at ColdFusion.Service.Authenticate.BasicAuthenticationProvider..cctor()

Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSni(DbAsyncResult asyncResult, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadNetworkPacket()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadBuffer()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadByte()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)
```

Comment: I wouldn't go to the hardware just yet. Do you have instrumentation data? Do you know whether something else might be happening at the same time? Maybe some periodic maintenance of the SQL server?

Comment: It's hard because I'm selling my software commercially so I don't have a huge leverage in terms of what I can install on the server. If you can suggest some useful tools it would be appreciated.